# sched_setaffinity() slows down a program with fftw3

Tags: c++, performance, openmp, fftw

I have encountered the following problem. I do some calculations and measure it's execution time. My code looks like:

```
void do_some_work()
{
  ...
}

int main()
{
  double tSt;
  double tFn;

//first do_work block
  tSt = omp_get_wtime();
  do_some_work();
  tFn = omp_get_wtime();
  cout << "1st work done for " << (tFn-tSt) << " s." << endl;

//second do_work block
  int cpus = 4;
  for(size_t cpuN=0; cpuN<cpus; ++cpuN)
  {
    cpu_set_t set;
    CPU_ZERO(&set);
    CPU_SET(cpuN, &set);
    sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(set), &set);

    tSt = omp_get_wtime();
    do_some_work();
    tFn = omp_get_wtime();
    cout << cpuN << " cpu - work done for " << (tFn-tSt) << " s." << endl;
  }

//third do_work block
  tSt = omp_get_wtime();
  do_some_work();
  tFn = omp_get_wtime();
  cout << "3rd work done for " << (tFn-tSt) << " s." << endl;
}
```

Actually I use it with OpenMP and run parallel. Here is simplified version that reproduce the problem.

The output looks like this:

> 1st work done for 0.100 s.
>
> 0 cpu - work done for 0.200 s.
>
> 1 cpu - work done for 0.200 s.
>
> 2 cpu - work done for 0.200 s.
>
> 3 cpu - work done for 0.200 s.
>
> 3rd work done for 0.200 s.

But SOMETIMES it looks like:

> 1st work done for 0.100 s.
>
> 0 cpu - work done for 0.200 s.
>
> 1 cpu - work done for 0.200 s.
>
> 2 cpu - work done for **0.100** s.
>
> 3 cpu - work done for 0.200 s.
>
> 3rd work done for 0.200 s.

So my qustions are:

1) Why execution time dramatically grows when I bind the thread to certain CPU?

2) Why execution time is still bad in 3rd call?

3) Why sometimes it is normal (it could happen on any cpu)?

Add on. Executable example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <fftw3.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  size_t N = 100000;

  fftwf_complex *in = (fftwf_complex*) fftwf_malloc(sizeof(fftwf_complex) * N);
  fftwf_complex *out = (fftwf_complex*) fftwf_malloc(sizeof(fftwf_complex) * N);

  fftwf_plan fft = fftwf_plan_dft_1d(N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);


  double tSt;
  double tFn;

//first do_work block
  tSt = omp_get_wtime();
  fftwf_execute(fft);
  tFn = omp_get_wtime();
  cout << "1st work done for " << (tFn-tSt) << " s." << endl;

//second do_work block
  // int cpus = omp_get_num_procs();
  int cpus = 4;
  for(size_t cpuN=0; cpuN<cpus; ++cpuN)
  {
    cpu_set_t set;
    CPU_ZERO(&set);
    CPU_SET(cpuN, &set);
    sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(set), &set);

    tSt = omp_get_wtime();
    fftwf_execute(fft);
    tFn = omp_get_wtime();
    cout << cpuN << " cpu - work done for " << (tFn-tSt) << " s." << endl;
  }

//third do_work block
  tSt = omp_get_wtime();
  fftwf_execute(fft);
  tFn = omp_get_wtime();
  cout << "3rd work done for " << (tFn-tSt) << " s." << endl;

  fftwf_free(in);
  fftwf_free(out);
  fftwf_destroy_plan(fft);
}
```

Compile: g++ -std=c++14 -O3 test.cpp -lfftw3f -fopenmp

Output (Xeon E5-2695 v4):

> 1st work done for 0.000572872 s.
>
> 0 cpu - work done for 0.00124588 s.
>
> 1 cpu - work done for 0.00131525 s.
>
> 2 cpu - work done for 0.00131468 s.
>
> 3 cpu - work done for 0.00129492 s.
>
> 3rd work done for 0.00125334 s.

Output (i7-6500u):

> 1st work done for 0.000400588 s.
>
> 0 cpu - work done for 0.00067104 s.
>
> 1 cpu - work done for 0.000504862 s.
>
> 2 cpu - work done for 0.000536624 s.
>
> 3 cpu - work done for 0.000439311 s.
>
> 3rd work done for 0.000432347 s.

Comment: what is inside `do_some_work`? Are you sure the compiler doesnt optimize it away? You dont use the return and other than timing the call seems to have no impact on your program. If I was a compiler I would say "Nah, just dont do it, anyhow he wont see the difference"

Comment: ...also it is a bit suspicious that your numbers have one significant digit only

Comment: /do_some_work' takes some values from memory, process them (fourier transform and some math operations) and then put back to memory. One significant digit is just for better reading - actually values are 0.099535, 0.098463, 0.102446 and so on.

Comment: Please provide a full [mcve] and your system specifications (CPU, Memory configuration, compiler, flags). Do **not** omit things for better reading!

Comment: Maybe, the first the time the data are allocated in the cpu-thread that will do_the_work, which means that all memory accesses will be cache hits. When you change cpu, then you will have cache miss? But you don't show the data initialization, i assume it is not done inside the do_the_work

Comment: to anybody who cares about the numbers 0.100 is worse to read than 0.099535

Comment: During the calculation, do you write any shared data between threads? (in do_some_work) - when writing to shared data, the performance might suffer if threads actually run each on different core because of cache thrashing. Note that the same applies for "false sharing" (data not shared per se, but share the same 64byte cache line).

Comment: guys, thanks for your comments - I'm trying to make minimal executable example to reproduce the problem - it seems the problem is in do_some_work procedure but i can't realize what it is for a while (it uses FFTW3 library and is some kind of blackbox); @axalis - the array in contiguous allocated in memory but each thread works with it's own part of memory

Comment: I second @tobi303, replacing the actual timing numbers with nicely round ones, especially when the output statement does not suggest any kind of rounding taking place, is **very misleading**. It could fool one into thinking that something is wrong with the time measurement routines..

Comment: I found that slowdown is present on Xeon E5-2695 v4 but there is no one on i7-6500u. Will do executable example soon.

Comment: This is not fftw3. If I put memmove() as do_some_work - the slow down is terribly high. I intend to close this question and open new with all I know now. Thanks a lot to all who wrote here - you turned me on the right path.